# what does "if (<name of a function>)" mean?

Tags: javascript

```
function addPrivateProperty(o,name,predicate){
    var value;
    o["get"+name]=function(){return value;};
    o["set"+name]=function(v){
        if (predicate && !predicate(v))
            throw Error("set"+name+": invalid value "+v);
        else
            value=v;
    };
}
var o={};
addPrivateProperty(o,"Name",function(x){return typeof x=="string";});
```

here,what does "if (predicate && !predicate(v))" return? when would it return true/false?

Comment: If `predicate` was passed and it fails when called on `v` then do something.

Comment: `addPrivateProperty(o, "Name")` would work, pass `undefined` as a `predicate`, and not perform a check, for example. Also, don’t use this pattern. It’s pretty horrible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done javascript in a while so you'll have to bear with me but if I remember correctly, all functions are just variables, so saying `if(predicate)` just means if predicate was defined. In this scope it means if a value (function) was supplied to the parameter.

So essentially `if (predicate && !predicate(v))` first checks to see if the function exists before calling it, because they do not want to call a function that doesnt exist

Comment: "if predicate was defined" — nope. *predicate* is effecively declared by including it in the formal parameter list, so it is defined (but at that point has not been assigned a value so it's set to *undefined* [per ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2)). Also, the test just sees if it has a value that evaluates to false, so it could be *undefined*, *null*, *NaN*, *0*, '' (empty string) or *false*.

Answer (score 0):

False if undefined, true otherwise

Comment: This is partially true, there are other conditions which are false

Comment: what kind of array `o["get"+name]` is?I have never been seen this kind of array before.Can you give a hint?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if (predicate && !predicate(v))` evaluates if predicate and the opposite of predicate(v) are both `true`.

This would be true for `predicate` or `!predicate(v)` being equal to anything other than **`null`**, **`false`**, **`undefined`**, **`0`**, **`NaN`**, or an empty string.

Comment: Or `NaN`, or the empty string. `null` is lowercase, by the way.

Comment: True.  There are so many possibilities that it's hard to list them all.

Comment: Actually, that covers them all. =D

Comment: I guess `null` is not case-insensitive like PHP.  Well, thank you for teaching me something today.

Comment: The trick is that while they all evaluate to *false* in a test, only some are `==` and none are `===`, one not even with itself! :-)